# H2O python split_frame throws exception

Tags: python, h2o

I am trying to split my h2o frame and I keep getting exception below, but I am able to see the split frames in the Flow UI. I tried to lookup documentation trying to find the how to load the frame I see in Flow UI into my python shell, but no luck with that either.

```
data = h2o.import_frame("train.csv")
Parse Progress: [##################################################] 100%
Imported train.csv. Parsed 878,035 rows and 5 cols

splits = data.split_frame(ratios=[0.80])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h2o/frame.py", line 598, in split_frame
    return [h2o.get_frame(i["name"]) for i in j["destination_frames"]]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h2o/h2o.py", line 183, in get_frame
    return H2OFrame.get_frame(frame_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h2o/frame.py", line 50, in get_frame
    res = h2o.H2OConnection.get_json("Frames/"+urllib.quote(frame_id))["frames"][0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h2o/connection.py", line 391, in get_json
    return __H2OCONN__._rest_json(url_suffix, "GET", None, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h2o/connection.py", line 400, in _rest_json
    raw_txt = self._do_raw_rest(url_suffix, method, file_upload_info, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h2o/connection.py", line 466, in _do_raw_rest
    .format(http_result.status_code,http_result.reason,method,url,detailed_error_msgs))
EnvironmentError: h2o-py got an unexpected HTTP status code:
 404 Not Found (method = GET; url = http://localhost:54321/3/Frames/train_part0.hex).
detailed error messages: Object 'train_part0.hex' not found for argument: key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was fixed in the latest stable release

http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-simons/7/index.html

python wasn't polling to wait for the split frame to finish before it went off to the next step (resulting in that not found exception)